# SELinux for embedded systems

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, yocto, selinux

Does someone have experiences mentioned the use of SELinux in embedded systems like Yokto?

My current project got a board support package without any SELinux stuff. The only thing i am able
to use is the default SELinux Kernel feature. So i have no predefined policies nor userspace tools.

I compiled the Linux Kernel with SELinux support enabled and set `SELINUXTYPE=targeted` in `/etc/selinux/config`.

The system needs to run only a single policy that controls a little number of services in the targeted way but leaves the other services untouched.

I have no experience using SELinux without predefined policies or build system for policies like Fedora.
So i need to compile the policy, put the binary in the board support package and burn it on a SD-card.

There is no serious information about that out there so i bought the SELinux Cookbook by Sven Vermeulen but it lacks also in terms of using SELinux on embedded systems.

It would rather be lovely if someone have experiences using a similar system or has some websites or books with good information to advise.

Thank you!

Comment: I guess you found this already: https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/meta-selinux/

Comment: Yes i did. But i am not able to integrate that in my board support package. I only have the standard kernel support for SELinux and have to manage that with policies.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried adding the metalayer for the reference policy and then starting from there ?

link to the metalayer:

https://github.com/SELinuxProject/refpolicy

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.